# How does the Unreal Engine 4 Event System work?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Without delving deep into the codebase I want to ask how are custom events, event dispatchers and in general the event handling mechanism handled in Unreal Engine 4? It is the best I have seen, it's impeccable; it practically allows anything to be called from anywhere else! Do they use an event Queue data structure or similar operation principle? What is the underlying data structure and algorithm used to engineer this event system in UE4? In other words, the creation, deletion, setup and dispatching of (custom) events. Anybody knows a few things on this, kindly share. This is a theory question but the programming mindset is mainly C++.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is using delegates (Or function pointers), Unreal have it's own delegate class implementation, which basically stores an array of pairs.

So in generic terms you'll have a class that holds a main event, for example, when collision is detected inside a C++ class, probably deep enough to be in touch with physics module.

This class will have a "delegate" which can receive any object with a function pointer. 
For example: YourPlayerBlueprint , OnCollide( params ).  (As well as you can add new functions to call, you can remove it).

Once this is set up, when the collision is detected will fire all the functions binded and will work as an event.

Moreover, (this is a guess) all the functions must be independent so it can be run in parallel improving performance.

If you are more interested on delegates and functions pointers I recommend check this "tutorial / explanation" 
https://blog.molecular-matters.com/2011/09/19/generic-type-safe-delegates-and-events-in-c/

Hope I help a little to understand events in unreal.